# UserControl in XAML with parameters (Win Store App)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I need to send parameters to my user control. I now how implement sending but I don't how to take this parameters.

My code:

```
<UserControls:ItemTemplateControl Parameter="23"/>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the code-behind of your `UserControl`, and use properties:

```
public class ItemTemplateControl : UserControl
{
     int _parameter;
     public int Parameter
     {
         get
         {
             return _parameter;
         }
         set
         {
             // do something with the given value
             _parameter = value; // set _parameter to the given value
         }
      }

      // your other UserControl code here
}
```

More about C# properties: [Properties (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)